# Why is this Choice command not working (batch-file)

Tags: batch-file, batch-choice

I have this

```
@echo off
:1
cls
echo Navigation: W-Up, S-Down, E-Enter
echo _________________________________
echo -(Option 1)
echo   Option 2
echo   Option 3
choice /c WSE /n
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto 3
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto 2
if ERRORLEVEL 3 goto opt1
:2
cls
echo Navigation: W-Up, S-Down, E-Enter
echo _________________________________
echo   Option 1
echo -(Option 2)
echo   Option 3
choice /c WSE /n
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto 1
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto 2
if ERRORLEVEL 3 goto opt2
:3
cls
echo Navigation: W-Up, S-Down, E-Enter
echo _________________________________
echo   Option 1
echo   Option 2
echo -(Option 3)
choice /c WSE /n
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto 2
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto 1
if ERRORLEVEL 3 goto opt3
:opt1
cls
echo You chose Option 1
pause >nul
exit
:opt2
cls
echo You chose Option 2
pause >nul
exit
:opt3
cls
echo You chose Option 3
pause >nul
exit
```

What it is supposed to do is look like a selection menu, but for some reason it just constantly loops through ":1" from lines 2 to 9 it just loops over and over again, why is it doing this? How do I make it not do this?

Comment: You have to reverse your if errorlevel, starting with the highest number. In fact `if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto 1` is interpreted as `if ERRORLEVEL is 1 or greater  goto 1` so the other IFs aren't  reached at all. The alternative is to compare `if %errorlevel%==1 ...` available with EnableExtensions (default)

Comment: Reading `help if` / `If /?` or [ss64.com/nt/if.html](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) helps

Answer (score 0):

Read `choice /?`.

---

According to that help page, errorlevel(s) are supposed to be checked in **reversed order**.

```
choice /c WSE /n
if ERRORLEVEL 3 goto opt3
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto 2
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto 1
```

Why? Because `if ERRORLEVEL 1` means `if %errorlevel% geq 1`. Alternatively, you can do:

```
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto 1
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto 2
if %errorlevel% equ 3 goto opt3
```

Or even crazier(but safer) with `findstr`.

```
set errlvl=%errorlevel:~-1%
echo "%errlvl%"| findstr /l /x /i """1""" && goto :1
echo "%errlvl%"| findstr /l /x /i """2""" && goto :2
echo "%errlvl%"| findstr /l /x /i """3""" && goto :opt3
```

We do not really need that `set` statement, but a precaution

---

Just another reminder, if the user pressed key(s) out of the "WSE", an annoyingly loud beep will occur. You may want to check out [my poorly title question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456194/how-to-use-special-characters-in-choice-command-batch-file) to find out methods of silencing them.